# Magento 2 - how to remove navigation menu linkage for tabs

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

In my default magento theme for desktop on hovering on the menu, sub-menu is opening. But in tabs when clicking on menu, menu is opening but its also redirecting to main navigation link.

expected behavior is in tab devices like ipad, when clicking on menu its should open the sub-menu. its shouldn't redirect to main menu.

How we can achieve this. thanks